# What is the official name for this indicator?

Tags: indicator, terminology

I distinctly remember that this type of indicator was named after a person. With reference to a particular period e.g. a week or month, it is computed as:

$$Ratio1(t) = \frac{Close(t) - Low(t)}{ High(t) - Low(t)} $$

or possibly associated with a similar formula such as:

$$Ratio2(t) = \frac{Open(t) - Low(t)}{ High(t) - Low(t)} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could call it a one period stochastic indicator.

I neither use, nor have any knowledge about technical indicators but a quick google search of the term  ["(close - low)/(high -low)"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22(close+-+low)%2F(high+-low)%22) indicates it is called the `internal bar strength indicator`. Alexander Pagonidis claims in [“The IBS Effect: Mean Reversion in Equity ETFs” (2013)](https://www.naaim.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/00V_Alexander_Pagonidis_The-IBS-Effect-Mean-Reversion-in-Equity-ETFs-1.pdf) that he is the first to discuss this indicator in the academic literature.

In general, it seems a [fast stochastic indicator (%K)](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Fast_Stochastic_vs_Slow_Stochastic) requires a period, not the same day. Adding to @nbbo2, this should be closely related to Williams %R, except it should be on a scale 0 to 100 instead of -100 to 0. Meaning if Williams %R is -45, you will get a reading of 54 in the %K and so forth. This is also supported by Wikipedia's entry about [stochastic oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_oscillator) where it is stated that Williams %R is the equivalent of %K, mirrored around the 0%-axis.

Answer (score 4):

In simple terms it is the position of Close (or Open) within the range, i.e. [Low,High]. It equals 1 if the Close is at the High, and equals 0 if you Close at the Low. The rest of the time it is in ]0,1[. And similarly for the Open.

It is useful in many contexts. At my shop we just called it "position within range".

Comment: It is closely related to Williams %R, but I don't think Larry Williams invented it, it is a very old idea IMO. https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/trading-investing/technical-analysis/technical-indicator-guide/williams-r

Answer (score 1):

It is called a "fast stochastic oscillator" when expressed as a percentage, and is a building block for the general stochastic oscillator, developed by George Lane.

Comment: Was this intended as an edit to your question, rather than an answer?

Comment: I luckily found the answer shortly after the question. So I posted it in case somebody had the same question.